# Try to add position fixed to nav

Tags: css

I have a menu like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67925/)

Problem is it go out from container like this image:

[image]

and that occurs because I add `position: fixed;` to make navbar stick on top on scrolling, how can I fix it to show it before fixed like this:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your nav-element

`margin-inline-end: 50px;`

Or use your preferred value

Comment: there's not such thing as `margin-end`

Answer (score 0):

Put the logo (src) outside the navbar . Make two separate div for navbar and logo. And use col-md to arrange it side by side

Comment: I changed it to https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/67926/ but logo is outside nav.. how can I put inside it?

Comment: Increase the padding of div contaning navbar